# How to correctly dispose array of strings to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

MadExcept says my app leaks "strings" memory on the following code:

```
for i := 0 to TotalSpans-1 do
begin
  if i = 0 then LastPos := 1;
  StartPos := PosEx(SubstrAtBegin, RawHtmlStr, LastPos);
  FinishPos := PosEx(SubstrAtEnd, RawHtmlStr, LastPos);
  Spans[i] := Copy(RawHtmlStr, StartPos, FinishPos - StartPos +
    Length(SubstrAtEnd));
  LastPos := FinishPos + Length(SubstrAtEnd);
end;
```

where `Spans` is an `array of string`.
The idea is to find the specific values in a long `RawHtmlStr`. For that purpose I first locate the well-known *adjacent* substrings and then copy the value from between them to a dynamic array of strings.

The whole thing is serialized to work in threads.
On the last run I parsed about 15k of `RawHtmlStr`s and there were 38 exceptions thrown (mostly `EIdReadTimeout` and `EIdSocketError`). I handled those exceptions on an upper lever (simply moving to the next item), but they somehow led to 34 `UnicodeString` leaks.

madExcept points to the following line:

```
Spans[i] := Copy(RawHtmlStr, StartPos, FinishPos - StartPos +
    Length(SubstrAtEnd));
```

as a source of evil.

At the moment the whole piece of code is NOT wrapped by `try..finally` block because I do not quite understand how to handle the disposal of string array (which, I thought, is being taken care of by Delphi, no?).

Will `Finalize(Spans)` do the garbage collection in this case?

Comment: If it's a normal array containing normal strings, simply nulling or calling SetLength(array, 0) should do the job just fine. Do you have evidence that suggests otherwise?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The compiler will dispose of the array when the object leaves scope. Your suggestion would just bring the life to an end sooner.

Comment: When it leaves scope, yes. If, on the other hand, you have to force the cleanup sooner than that for whatever reason, such as MadExcept being run before this (I'm not familiar with MadExcept and its details).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen madExcept's leak detection runs very late indeed. I'm quite sure everything has left scope by the time it runs.

Comment: OK, but that leaves my question, is there any evidence that the given array of strings is a memory leak, other than MadExcept, because it sounds to me as it should've been cleaned up by then.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen madExcept's leak detection is exceptionally good. I'd be astounded if these were not real leaks. And so the most likely explanation is that the container of the array of strings was never finalized. Of course, stuffing in code to finalise the array explicitly would suppress those leaks, but the root problem would remain.

Comment: threading wil likely be the issue here, but we can't know until you provide an SSCCE...

Answer (score 4):

The object in question is of type

```
array of string
```

That is a dynamic array whose lifetime is managed by reference counting. The members of the array also have lifetime managed by reference count.

With managed objects you do not need to take any steps to dispose of them. At some point, when the final reference to the object leaves scope, the object is automatically destroyed.

So, if you are leaking such an object that would usually imply that whatever contains the object is not being destroyed. For example, this code would leak an array of strings:

```
type
  TRec = record
    arr: array of string;
  end;
  PRec = ^TRec;
....
var
  Rec: PRec;
....
New(Rec);
SetLength(Rec.arr, 42);
Rec.arr[0] := 'foo';
// and so on
```

If you failed to dispose of `Rec` then it, and its contents, would be leaked.

Likewise if you have a class that owns managed objects, and that class is leaked, then all the members of the class are also leaked.

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    arr: array of string;
  end;
....
var
  Obj: TMyClass;
....
Obj := TMyClass.Create;
SetLength(Obj.arr, 42);
Obj.arr[0] := 'foo';
// and so on
```

Again, if you fail to destroy `Obj`, then it will leak, and so will its members.

Beyond that scenario, the only other way that I can imagine a managed type leaking is if a heap corruption overwrites the reference count.

Comment: What if the array is a global one? I could imagine that it is not freed before MadExcept catches it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis madExcept's leak checking runs after the program's units have been finalised. It would be useless otherwise wouldn't it.

Comment: I don't know when maxExcept's leak checking takes place. It would not be useless, but indeed less useful than when it runs after all units have been finalized.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I do know when it takes place. It would be utterly useless if it ran too early. Who would write leak detection software that always reported false positives? Who would use it?

Comment: Another leak of strings: If you have a record with a string, und you do a `FillChar()` over the whole record to reset the data, the string will leak.